# Which versions of Kotlin are compatible with which versions of Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I know Kotlin requires Java when running Kotlin. For example, I use Kotlin 1.4.0 and I use Java 14. However, I'm not sure about Kotlin and Java version compatibility.

Is there a Kotlin and Java version compatibility table?

I looked through [the official document](https://kotlinlang.org/), but I couldn't find the information that I wanted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Which versions of JVM does Kotlin target?**
>
> Kotlin lets you choose the version of JVM for execution. By default,
> the Kotlin/JVM compiler produces Java 8 compatible bytecode. If you
> want to make use of optimizations available in newer versions of Java,
> you can explicitly specify the target Java version from 9 to 18

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#which-versions-of-jvm-does-kotlin-target

Answer (score 30):

The following table shows the Kotlin compiler version that had first started supporting each new JVM target:

| Kotlin version | Release date | JVM targets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 15/2/2016 | 1.6 only |
| 1.1 | 7/2/2017 | 1.6 to 1.8 |
| 1.3.30 | 11/4/2019 | 1.6 to 12 |
| 1.3.70 | 3/3/2020 | 1.6 to 13 |
| 1.4.0 | 14/8/2020 | 1.6 to 14 |
| 1.4.20 | 19/11/2020 | 1.6 to 15 |
| 1.5.0 | 26/4/2021 | 1.6 to 16 |
| 1.6.0 | 16/11/2021 | 1.8 to 17 |
| 1.6.20 | 4/4/2022 | 1.8 to 18 |
| 1.8.0 | 28/12/2022 | 1.8 to 19 |
| 1.9.0 | 6/7/2023 | 1.8 to 20 |
| 1.9.20 | 1/11/2023 | 1.8 to 21 |

Comment: Thanks! Where do you have this matrix from?

Comment: @MarianKlühspies this matrix doesn't exist anywhere else as far as I know. I worked it out by installing successive versions of the Kotlin compiler command line and trying them out.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the effort. It's quite a missing piece on their official site. I was googling around to figure out why Kotlin does not seem to work with JDK 21 yet and found your post.